# Moodle's css and js file not loading

Tags: php, nginx, moodle

[image]

- moodle version:3.1.3
- server:nginx
- database:mysql
- os:ubuntu

I can't load `css` and `js` files

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  You need to add a description to that image link, you need to add far more detail about the context you get the error in, you need to read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just not use subfolder. Or you should set correct baseUrl in app or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849456/nginx-reverse-proxy-404-on-static-files/40737913#40737913